# Solving non-convex optimization with global optimization algorithm using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, optimization, mathematical-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I have a simple unconstrained non-convex optimization problem. Since problems of these type have multiple local minima, I am looking for global optimization algorithm that yields a unique/global minimum. In the internet I came across global optimization algorithms like genetic algorithms, simulated annealing, etc but for solving a simple one variable unconstrained non-convex optimization problem, I think using these high level algorithms doesn't seem to be a good idea. Could anyone recommend me a simple global algorithm for solving such simple one variable unconstrained non-convex optimization problem? I would highly appreciate ideas on this.

Comment: You can use the global optimization toolbox's global search or multistart functions: http://www.mathworks.com/products/global-optimization/features.html#global-search-and-multistart-solvers

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I currently don't have global optimization toolbox. Is there any other alternative?

Comment: write your own multistart procedure? Just pick many different starting points at random and run a local optimization for each. The pick the best one at the end

Comment: Seems a good idea. Is 'fminsearch' of MATLAB a good local optimization algorithm?Or any other suggestions?

Comment: Why don't you try it and find out

Comment: Yes I am trying to solve using this algorithm; I just wanted to know if there are better alternatives.

Comment: Note that genetic algorithms (GA:s) is not, per se, a _"global optimization method"_, but a stochastic optimization method that can yield good results in non-convex optimization problems. There is, however, no guarantee that you will reach a global optimum using GA:s. Anyway, for this the simple problem of a the global min. or max. of a single-variable function, have a look at particle swarm optimization (PSO). It's a bit simpler to implement from scratch than a GA, and usually yields "OK" results for instances such as this one. Note, however, that there's no guarantee of optimality.

Comment: A simple approach would be to evaluate the function for a grid of of points (xlo, xlo+step,xlo+2*step,...,xup). Pick the best point and use that as starting point for a local optimization routine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Since problems of these type have multiple local minima". It's not true, the real situation is the following:

- Maybe you have one local minimum
- Maybe you have infinite set of local miminums
- Maybe you have finite number of local minimums
- Maybe minimum is not attained
- Maybe problem is unbounded below

Also big picture is that there are really true methods which really solve problems (numerically and they slow), but there is a slang to call method which is not nessesary find minumum value of function also call as "solve".

---

1. In fact M^n~M for any finite n and any infinite set M. So the fact that you problem has one dimension is nothing. It is still hard as problem with 1000000 parameters which are drawn from the set M from theoretical point of view.
2. If you interesting how approximately solve problem with known precision epsilon in domain - then split you domain into 1/espsilon regions, sample value(evalute function) at middle point, and select minimum
3. Method which I will describe below is precise method, and other methods: particle estimation, sequent.convex.programming, alternative direction, particle swarm, Neidler-Mead simplex method, mutlistart gradient/subgradient descend or any descend algorithm like Newton Method or coordinate descend, they **all** has no gurantess for non-convex problems and some of them even can no be applied if function is nonconvex.

---

If you interesting in really solve with some precision on function value then then you can take attention into method, which is called **branch-and-bound** and which truly found minimum, algorithms which you described I don't think so that they solve problem and find minimum in strong sense:

Basic idea of branch and bound - partition domain into convex sets and improve lower/upper bound, in your case it is intervals.

You should have a routine to find upper bound of optimal (min.) value: you can do it e.g. just by sampling subdomain and take smallest or use local optimization method start from random point.

But also you should have lower bound of optimal (min.) value by some principle and this is hard part:

- convex relaxation of integer variables to make them real variables
- use Lagrange Dual function
- use Lipshitc constant on function, etc.

This is sophisticaed step.

If this two values are near - we're done in other case partion or refine partition.

Get info about lower and upper bound of child subproblems and then take min. of upper bounds and min. of lower bounds of children. If child returns more worse lower bound it can be upgraded by parent.

---

**References:**

For more great explanation please look into:
EE364B, Lecture 18, prof. Stephen Boyd, Stanford University. It's available on youtube and in ITunes University. If you new to this area I recommend you to look EE263, EE364A, EE364B courses of Stephen P. Boyd. You will love it

Answer (score -2):

Since this is a one dimensional problem, things are easier.
A simple steepest descend procedure may be used as follows.
Suppose the interval of search is `a<x<b`.

Start the SD from a minimizing your function say f(x). You recover the first minimum Xm1. You should use a fine step, not too large. 
Shift this point by adding a positive small constant Xm1+ε. Then maximize f or minimize -f, starting from this point. You get a max of f, you distort it by ε and start from there a minimization, and so on so forth.